# How to convert blocking IEnumerable to Akka actor

Tags: c#, akka.net

I would like to convert a blocking IEnumerable (possibly infinite) into messages sent to an Actor.  What is the best way to do this?  I am currently attempting to create a `Task` within an actor on `PreStart` and inside the task have it send messages to but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've read some pages about preferring to use `PipeTo` to wrap a `Task` but that seems to only be used to retrieve a single result rather than have a separate process continually sending values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Akka.Actor;

namespace Junk
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var system = ActorSystem.Create("my-system");
            var actor = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new Manager()));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Manager : ReceiveActor
    {
        private Task _task;

        public Manager() {
          Receive<uint>(msg => { Console.WriteLine($"received {msg}"); });
        }

        protected override void PreStart() {
          Console.WriteLine($"{Self} - PreStart --------------");
          startTask();
        }

        private void startTask() {
          _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            BlockingEnumerable source = new BlockingEnumerable();
            Console.WriteLine($"task starting loop -------------");
            foreach (uint v in source) {
              Self.Tell(v);
            }
          });
        }
    }

    public class BlockingEnumerable : IEnumerable<uint>
    {
        public IEnumerator<uint> GetEnumerator() { return new BlockingEnumerator(); }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }

    public class BlockingEnumerator : IEnumerator<uint>
    {
        private uint value = 0;
        public uint Current => value;
        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
        public void Dispose() { }
        public bool MoveNext() { Thread.Sleep(2000); value += 1; return true; }
        public void Reset() { value = 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [BlockingCollection<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you need it for? Maybe Akka.Streams is what you actually want?

Comment: I am streaming extended events from SQL Server and the interface provided (that I can find) is an IEnumerable.  I would like to have these stream sessions managed by an actor and subscribe-able by other actors or other outputs.  I'll take a look to see if Akka.Streams provides something.

Comment: If you're using Akka.Persistence eventsourcing, then SQL journals do have support for something called Peristence Queries, which expose event streams into format readable from Akka.Streams API.